# How can I align my textboxes perfectly?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, textbox, alignment

https://i.stack.imgur.com/eujeL.jpg

As you can see here, my textboxes doesn't seem to be aligned perfectly after each other.

```
<body style="background-color:#004590;">
</body>
<p>
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" ForeColor="#3366FF" Text="*Welcome to the Library Management System*"></asp:Label>
<p>
    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" BackColor="#66CCFF" BorderColor="Black" BorderStyle="Groove" Text="Sign Up Page:" Width="135p&nbsp;<p>
    &nbsp;<p>
    I am a:<p>
    <asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged1" Rows="3"></asp:ListBox>
<p>
    Username:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

Please enter a Username.

ID:                               
        
        ID should be between 11111-99999.

E-Mail:                         
        
        Please enter a valid E-Mail address.

Password:                   
        
        Please choose a password.

Confirm Password:      
        
        Password does not match.

Comment: paste you html code please

Comment: Done, this is the source code from design page

Comment: And they're not going to be aligned perfectly either; using a non-breaking space `&nbsp;` for spacing is not a recommended approach for aligning elements. Time to get some CSS knowledge, my friend - https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_align.asp

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to say just looking at the picture, try posting some of your code. If you're using labels before textboxes, try setting a fixed width for labels.

Comment: I haven't used any codes for the textboxes, I just aligned them manually and used properties for height and width, didn't do anything for their design in cs. Didn't use any labels before them.

Answer (score 0):

You can check your textboxes X and Y positions, depend on your vertical requirement you can set it up. It should work. Hope this helps.

Comment: Okay how can I do this?